# Hilt: error when provide Retrofit service

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, dagger-hilt

I am trying to integrate Hilt into my Android app. All was fine until I add Hilt to provide Retrofit service with weird error:

```
Cause: not a valid name: default
```

Full stacktrace:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:hiltJavaCompileDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:142)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:327)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:307)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:293)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:417)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:339)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a valid name: default
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:163)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.IncrementalCompileTask.call(IncrementalCompileTask.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.call(AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.call(ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.execute(ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.execute(ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.java:36)
    at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.DefaultToolchainJavaCompiler.execute(DefaultToolchainJavaCompiler.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.lambda$createToolchainCompiler$1(JavaCompile.java:232)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompiler.execute(CleaningJavaCompiler.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory.lambda$createRebuildAllCompiler$0(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.SelectiveCompiler.execute(SelectiveCompiler.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.SelectiveCompiler.execute(SelectiveCompiler.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.execute(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:279)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performIncrementalCompilation(JavaCompile.java:165)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:146)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalInputsTaskAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:236)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:204)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:181)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:254)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:209)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:281)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:139)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:327)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:307)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:293)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:417)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:339)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a valid name: default
    at com.squareup.javapoet.Util.checkArgument(Util.java:53)
    at com.squareup.javapoet.MethodSpec$Builder.setName(MethodSpec.java:315)
    at com.squareup.javapoet.MethodSpec$Builder.<init>(MethodSpec.java:310)
    at com.squareup.javapoet.MethodSpec$Builder.<init>(MethodSpec.java:294)
    at com.squareup.javapoet.MethodSpec.methodBuilder(MethodSpec.java:188)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.InjectionMethods.methodProxy(InjectionMethods.java:380)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.InjectionMethods.access$000(InjectionMethods.java:87)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.InjectionMethods$ProvisionMethod.create(InjectionMethods.java:132)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.InjectionMethods$ProvisionMethod.invoke(InjectionMethods.java:158)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.SimpleMethodRequestRepresentation.invokeInjectionMethod(SimpleMethodRequestRepresentation.java:137)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.SimpleMethodRequestRepresentation.getDependencyExpression(SimpleMethodRequestRepresentation.java:90)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentRequestRepresentations.getDependencyExpression(ComponentRequestRepresentations.java:115)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.DelegateRequestRepresentation.getDependencyExpression(DelegateRequestRepresentation.java:82)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentRequestRepresentations.getDependencyExpression(ComponentRequestRepresentations.java:115)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentRequestRepresentations.getDependencyArgumentExpression(ComponentRequestRepresentations.java:185)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.SimpleMethodRequestRepresentation.dependencyArgument(SimpleMethodRequestRepresentation.java:152)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.SimpleMethodRequestRepresentation.lambda$invokeMethod$0(SimpleMethodRequestRepresentation.java:100)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.InjectionMethods$ProvisionMethod.invokeArguments(InjectionMethods.java:180)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.SimpleMethodRequestRepresentation.invokeMethod(SimpleMethodRequestRepresentation.java:98)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.SimpleMethodRequestRepresentation.getDependencyExpression(SimpleMethodRequestRepresentation.java:91)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.SwitchingProviders$SwitchingProviderBuilder.createSwitchCaseCodeBlock(SwitchingProviders.java:153)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.SwitchingProviders$SwitchingProviderBuilder.getNewInstanceCodeBlock(SwitchingProviders.java:128)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.SwitchingProviders$SwitchingProviderBuilder.access$100(SwitchingProviders.java:110)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.SwitchingProviders$1.creationExpression(SwitchingProviders.java:93)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.FrameworkFieldInitializer.initializeField(FrameworkFieldInitializer.java:99)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.FrameworkFieldInitializer.memberSelect(FrameworkFieldInitializer.java:88)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.SwitchingProviderInstanceSupplier.memberSelect(SwitchingProviderInstanceSupplier.java:62)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.FrameworkInstanceRequestRepresentation.getDependencyExpression(FrameworkInstanceRequestRepresentation.java:51)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentRequestRepresentations.getDependencyExpression(ComponentRequestRepresentations.java:115)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.DelegateRequestRepresentation.getDependencyExpression(DelegateRequestRepresentation.java:82)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentRequestRepresentations.getDependencyExpression(ComponentRequestRepresentations.java:115)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.MapRequestRepresentation.keyAndValueExpression(MapRequestRepresentation.java:146)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.MapRequestRepresentation.getDependencyExpression(MapRequestRepresentation.java:105)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.RequestRepresentation.getDependencyExpressionForComponentMethod(RequestRepresentation.java:42)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentMethodRequestRepresentation.getDependencyExpressionForComponentMethod(ComponentMethodRequestRepresentation.java:66)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentRequestRepresentations.getComponentMethodExpression(ComponentRequestRepresentations.java:240)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentRequestRepresentations.getContributionComponentMethodImplementation(ComponentRequestRepresentations.java:233)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentRequestRepresentations.getComponentMethod(ComponentRequestRepresentations.java:204)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentImplementation$ShardImplementation.addInterfaceMethods(ComponentImplementation.java:880)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentImplementation$ShardImplementation.generate(ComponentImplementation.java:713)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentImplementation.generate(ComponentImplementation.java:434)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentImplementation$ShardImplementation.addChildComponents(ComponentImplementation.java:890)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentImplementation$ShardImplementation.generate(ComponentImplementation.java:714)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentImplementation.generate(ComponentImplementation.java:434)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentImplementation$ShardImplementation.addChildComponents(ComponentImplementation.java:890)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentImplementation$ShardImplementation.generate(ComponentImplementation.java:714)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.ComponentImplementation.generate(ComponentImplementation.java:434)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.componentgenerator.ComponentGenerator.topLevelTypes(ComponentGenerator.java:61)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.componentgenerator.ComponentGenerator.topLevelTypes(ComponentGenerator.java:32)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.base.SourceFileGenerator.generate(SourceFileGenerator.java:76)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.base.SourceFileGenerator.generate(SourceFileGenerator.java:68)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.processingstep.ComponentProcessingStep.generateComponent(ComponentProcessingStep.java:126)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.processingstep.ComponentProcessingStep.processRootComponent(ComponentProcessingStep.java:111)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.processingstep.ComponentProcessingStep.process(ComponentProcessingStep.java:87)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.processingstep.ComponentProcessingStep.process(ComponentProcessingStep.java:49)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.processingstep.TypeCheckingProcessingStep.lambda$process$0(TypeCheckingProcessingStep.java:81)
    at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.forEach(RegularImmutableMap.java:196)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.processingstep.TypeCheckingProcessingStep.process(TypeCheckingProcessingStep.java:69)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.processingstep.TypeCheckingProcessingStep.process(TypeCheckingProcessingStep.java:47)
    at dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.XProcessingStep.process(XProcessingStep.kt:59)
```

What could be wrong in my implementation?

The AppModule for providing Retrofit and Retrofit's service:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class AppModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun defaultDispatcherProvider(defaultDispatcherProvider: DefaultDispatcherProvider): DispatcherProvider

    companion object {
        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun retrofit(): Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://moviesdatabase.p.rapidapi.com")
            .client(HttpClientBuilder.default().build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(NetworkAdapterFactory())
            .build()

        @Provides
        fun titleService(retrofit: Retrofit): TitleService = retrofit.create(TitleService::class.java)
    }

}
```

ViewModelModule for providing necessary services for view model:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun titleRepository(titleRepositoryImpl: TitleRepositoryImpl): TitleRepository

    @Binds
    abstract fun remoteTitleDataSource(titleRemoteDataSourceImpl: TitleRemoteDataSourceImpl): TitleRemoteDataSource
}
```

My View model:

```
class GetTitleWithRatingListGroupByGenre @Inject constructor(private val titleRepository: TitleRepository) {
    suspend fun getTitleWithRatingListGroupByGenre(): ResultDomain<Map<String, List<TitleWithRatingDomain>>> {
        return titleRepository.getTitleWithRatingListGroupByGenre()
    }
}

class TitleRemoteDataSourceImpl @Inject constructor(private val titleService: TitleService)

@HiltViewModel
class TitleWithRatingViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getTitleWithRatingListGroupByGenre: GetTitleWithRatingListGroupByGenre,
    private val dispatcherProvider: DispatcherProvider
) : ViewModel() {
```

Comment: Can you add full stacktrace of error ?

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70344983/execution-failed-for-task-apphiltjavacompiledebug

Answer (score 0):

My understanding from  the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#inject-provides), I think because **AppModule**
is injecting with @Provide not @Bind, try changing AppModule to an object instead of abstract class and remove the companion object inside.

```
    @Module
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    object AppModule {
...
    }
```

Comment: Actually, AppModule is an abstract class because I also need to provide an implementation of DispatcherProvider. I have updated the code